# Python pandas merge and save with existed sheets

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas

i want merge multi excel file(1.xlsm, 2.xlsm....) to [A.xlsm] file with macro, 3sheets

so i try to merge

```
# input_file = (./*.xlsx)
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in (input_file):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True, sort=False)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(A.xlsm, engine='openpyxl')
all_data.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

the code dose not error, 
but result file[A.xlsm] is error to open,

so i change extension to A.xlsx and open.

it opening is OK but disappear all Sheets and macro.

how can i merge multi xlsx file to xlsm file with macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that if you want to use macro-enabled workbooks you need to load them with `keep_vba=True`:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
XlMacroFile = load_workbook('A.xlsm',keep_vba=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! it work well. I have to study overwrite sheet next.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve separate sheets, you can do something like

```
df_list = #list of your dataframes
filename = #name of your output file

with pd.ExcelWriter(filename) as writer:
    for df in df_list:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet_name_goes_here')
```

This will write each dataframe in a separate sheet in your output excel file.